# What is the recommended method to compress decimal into case insensitive string?

Tags: java, performance, character-encoding

I have a messaging system that uses REST, Websockets AND Files on disk to convey messages with Java both side of the connections.  The messages that are sent are then used as security tokens to query various indexes and databases and here size is crucial.  I have considered things like Base64.encodeBase64() with the Long as a byte array but this is case sensitive and also not much saving in terms of space.  I have considered converting to hex and toString() on that but the saving is small compared.  I would expect that there is an industry standard for something like this and I am either being very unlucky, being an idiot and overlooking something very obvious or using the wrong language.  There is no actual requirement to decode the string to long as the token is used as is on the other side, it just must be unique, repetable, reliable and small.

I must be able to send the tokens as plain strings

I must be able to repetably encode the Long to string

The tokens must be case insensitive (a == A)

The tokens must be as compressed as possible, size is important

The Long values have no leading 0's, no negative numbers, no decimal places

Comment: What about using a [Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash) or a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)?

Comment: in terms of UUID the Long value is already  unique and system generated and outside my control, its just how to send that in as small a payload as possible.  A hash will just return the primitive number anyway which still has to be converted to a string before it can be transmitted.

Comment: I suppose with that constraints you cannot do much better than with a Base32 encoding (e.g. using Apache Commons::Codec)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, so far its better than what I have, its not massive saving but it is some and I dont want to go defining my own character set and encoding logic.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 is only appropriate when you have case sensitivity.

Fundamentally you need to determine how many characters you can use as a symbol set, and this determines how compact the strings will be. The more symbols, the more compact the strings.

It sounds like you can use all letters in say upper case and all digits. This gives you 36 symbols, and strings up to `ceil(log(2^64)/log(36))` characters i.e. 13.

e.g.

```
String s = Long.toString(x, 36);
long l = Long.parseLong(s, 36);
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I was missing, I will experiment and get back and accept later on when I have tested it :-)